# How to use a wildcard in switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have data returned from an ajax call: `INSERT_OK_something`.

I would like to use a switch statement with a wildcard like `INSERT_OK_*` and pass "something" like a id variable to my url.

```
switch (data) {
case "ERROR":
        $("#alert").dialog( "open" ).html( "Error" );
        return false;

case "INSERT_OK_*":
    var url = "index.php?op=ok&id=" + something;
    window.location = url ;
    return false; 
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This little trick will do (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzXGr/)):

```
var data = "INSERT_OK_BLABLA";

switch (data) {
case "INSERT_OK_" + data.slice("INSERT_OK_".length): // emulate INSERT_OK_*
    var url = "index.php?op=ok&id=" + data.slice("INSERT_OK_".length);
    alert(url);
    break;
default:
    alert("default");
    break;
}
```

or using `startsWith` (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr3da4jw/)):

```
switch (true) {
case data.startsWith("INSERT_OK_"):
    var url = "index.php?op=ok&id=" + data.slice("INSERT_OK_".length);
    alert(url);
    break;
default:
    alert("default");
    break;
}
```